# How to fix wrong alignment of vector annotation head in Matlab if y-Direction is set to 'reverse'

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

the code

```
figure
scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
ax = gca;
ax.YDir = 'reverse'
ah = annotation('arrow','position',[ 2.5 2.5 -1 -1]);
set(ah,'parent',ax);
```

gives a wrong vector head alignment:

[image: plot with reverse arrow]

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: You should send a bug report to the MathWorks.

Comment: The mathworks answer: "According to the code you have sent, you set the parent of the annotation object to be the axes of the figure.
This is undocumented and unsupported behavior, as the only intended parent for an annotation object is a figure, a uipanel, or a uitab [...] As such, the behavior shown with reversing 'YDim' is not a bug, since the annotation object is not being used in the correct way." So the @CrisLuengo's answer is probably the right way to go.

Comment: @obchardon: This is so annoying! We really need an arrow that we can place based on axes coordinates, like we can place `text` anywhere in the figure based on axes coordinates. My answer is sub-optimal because you can’t change anything about the axes without making the arrow point in the wrong place. External solutions also don’t work well eg when you change the aspect ratio of the figure. There is currently no good, universal, robust solution for placing an arrow in a plot. :(

Answer (score 4):

One way to deal with the problem is to create the arrow and the line with two separated annotation:

```
figure
scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
ax = gca;
ax.YDir = 'reverse'

%Define the variable
xac = 2.5; %x arrow coordinate
yac = 2.5; %y arrow coordinate
xas = -1;   %x arrow shift
yas = -1;   %y arrow shift

if get(ax,'Ydir') == 'reverse':
   %Create the arrow
   ah1 = annotation('arrow','position',[ xac yac+2*yas xas -yas],'linestyle','none');
   set(ah1,'parent',ax);
   %Create the line
   ah2 = annotation('arrow','position',[ xac yac xas yas],'headstyle','none');
   set(ah2,'parent',ax);
else:
   ah = annotation('arrow','position',[ xac yac xas yas]);
   set(ah,'parent',ax);
end
```

Where the arrow coordinate are now `xac yac+2*yas xas -yas`,

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Good band-aid fix, but this code will give a wrong arrow head when they fix this bug! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Indeed ! I've reported the bug to mathworks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Annotate](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63760-annotate) from the Matlab File Exchange:

```
fig = figure;
scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
ax = gca;
ax.YDir = 'reverse';
Annotate(ax, 'arrow',[2.5 1.5],[2.5 1.5])
```

This way you are not dependent on Mathworks to fix the bug, but you need to download additional files...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html#br2_upx-1-container), the `annotation` object should be inside "a figure, uipanel, or uitab object". Putting it inside an axes object is not intended use.

Instead, compute the locations of your arrow w.r.t. the figure itself. You can do this as follows:

```matlab
figure;
scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3]);
ax = gca;
ax.YDir = 'reverse';

% Original arrow definition
origin = [2.5,2.5];
direction = [-1,-1];

% Convert coordinates from axes to figure
origin = origin - [ax.XLim(1),ax.YLim(1)];
origin = origin ./ [diff(ax.XLim),-diff(ax.YLim)]; % minus for inverse Y axis
origin(2) = origin(2) + 1; % for inverse Y axis
origin = origin .* ax.Position(3:4) + ax.Position(1:2);

direction = direction ./ [diff(ax.XLim),-diff(ax.YLim)]; % minus for inverse Y axis
direction = direction .* ax.Position(3:4);

% Draw arrow in figure
ah = annotation('arrow','position',[origin,direction]);
```

You could make a simple function that does this computation. The bits needed to invert the y-axis can be conditional upon `ax.YDir == 'reverse'`.